# How to accept attributes for two models in one form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a Rails newbie trying to accept nested attributes for model Address through model Vault 'new' form, but I am getting an undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass ERROR

I have two Models, a Vault Model here:

```
class Vault < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and I also have an Address Model here:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vault
end
```

This is my Vault_controller 'new' methodd:

```
  def new
    @vault = Vault.new
    @vault.address.build
  end
```

This is part of my _form.html.erb Vault partial, where I am trying to capture the info for the Address model:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :address do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :stnumber, "St. Number" %></br>
    <%= builder.text_field :stnumber %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #vault.rb
class Vault < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, dependent: :destroy
  #Other codes goes here
end

 #address.rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :vault
  #other code goes here.
end
```

## Build Address(depending on association)

```
 v = Vault.new 
 address = v.address.build 
 # this one will work only for has_many association.

 address = v.build_address 
 #this one will work for your has_one association
```

Please check [this link.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to-label-Example)

Comment: aha!, thats fixed the problem. appreciate your prompt response.

Comment: Added a better clarification ! please check, this will surely help you in long go. Hope it helps :)

Comment: yes, that will definately help in the long run.. i do plan has_many assosciations in the future. I would have found myself in the same predicament.